# Peculiar writef/writefln behavior?

Tags: d

So I've been looking at D for about 15 mins, so it's no wonder I have questions, but something strange is happening for me.

I installed D from [here](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/download.html) and Visual D from [here](http://dsource.org/projects/visuald) and I'm running everything in Visual Studio 2010 Professional. D examples compile and run and the debugger appears to be working fine.

While going through [dsource.org's fundamental tutorials](http://www.dsource.org/projects/tutorials/wiki/TutorialFundamentals), I was reading the [Wait](http://www.dsource.org/projects/tutorials/wiki/WaitExample/D1) section when I noticed that if you use `writef` instead of `writefln` then the last line of the output prints *after* the pause.

Here's the example's code:

```
import std.c.stdio; /* for getch() */
import std.process; /* for system() */
import std.stdio; /* for writefln */

void main() { 
    writefln("Press a key (using 'std.c.stdio.getch();' to wait) . . .");
    getch();

    writefln("Waiting again\n(using 'system(\"pause\");'):");
    system("pause");
}
```

And here's mine, note the only change is `writefln` to `writef`

```
import std.c.stdio; /* for getch() */
import std.process; /* for system() */
import std.stdio; /* for writefln */

void main() { 
    writef("Press a key (using 'std.c.stdio.getch();' to wait) . . .");
    getch();

    writef("Waiting again\n(using 'system(\"pause\");'):");
    system("pause");
}
```

With `writef` the program will display nothing on the screen, pause at `getch`, then when I press a key I see the prompt:

```
Press a key (using 'std.c.stdio.getch();' to wait) . . .Waiting again
Press any key to continue . . .
```

but NOT "(using 'system("pause");'):". The parenthetic statement appears after I press a key to get through the 'pause' command in the console. If I use `writefln` it prints, waits, prints both lines, then waits again as you'd expect.

What explains this behavior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `stdout.flush();` after any calls to `write` or `writef`. These latter calls don't flush the buffer, which is why you're seeing this behavior. Btw `getch` is not in `std.c.stdio` (at least not in D2?), it's in DMC's CRT library (SNN.lib), and to properly use it you would have to prototype it as `extern (C) int getch();`:

```
extern (C) int getch();
import std.process; /* for system() */
import std.stdio; /* for writefln */

void main() { 
    writef("Press a key (using 'std.c.stdio.getch();' to wait) . . .");
    stdout.flush();
    getch();

    writef("Waiting again\n(using 'system(\"pause\");'):");
    stdout.flush();
    system("pause");
}
```

But this is not cross-platform compatible due to `getch()`. If you want to use a nicer user-input facility you can check out Jesse's cmdln library: https://github.com/he-the-great/JPDLibs/tree/cmdln. It has a rather cool interface:

```
auto num = require!(int, "a > 0 && a <= 10")("Enter a number from 1 to 10");
```

Comment: Might you elaborate on the `extern` line? I removed the unnecessary import, but the code works without the `extern`, too.

Comment: Which compiler are you using? With 2.057 without prototyping getch I get `Error: undefined identifier getch, did you mean function getc?`

Answer (score 4):

[This thread on `gmane.comp.lang.d.learn`](http://blog.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.d.learn/month=20090701/page=19) seems to [indicate](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.d.learn/2874) that `writef` only flushes the output when it encounters a newline. Since `writefln` is a simple call to `writef` with a newline appended, `writefln` always flushes the output. All text after the last newline is buffered until the end of the program.